# como imprimir 2 columnas con Dompdf desde PHP

Tags: php, dompdf

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<body>
  <div>

    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; ">
      <table>
        <!-- Aquí van los datos de la columna  1 -->
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style=" float: right; width: 45%; margin-top: 0.5cm; ">
      <table>
        <!-- Aquí van los datos de la columna  2 -->
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Cuando las tablas no pasan de una página, se mantienen alineadas una al lado de la otra; al pasar de 2 páginas o más, la segunda tabla se imprime al terminarse de generar la primera tabla. Necesito hacer que esta se inicie a generar o imprimirse desde la primera página manteniendo el orden de 2 columnas una al lado de la otra.

Intenté con `display: flex;` pero dompdf no reconoce esa propiedad.

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido, DomPDF no es capaz de hacer lo que pides. Yo también tenía que sacar dos columnas, como tu indicas y en caso de que una sea larga, y pase de página, se desmonta todo. La solución que encontré fue calcular cuantas líneas me entran en cada página, y controlar que en caso de que pase ese número de líneas, haga un salto de líneas y siga escribiendo en la siguiente página. En mi caso las dos tablas tenían el mismo contenido, pero esto también te puede servir aunque tengan distinto contenido. Si esto te sirve, tendrás que pensar como escribir X líneas por página.

Comment: me podrías indicar con un ejemplo  como  hacerlo  para probarlos por favor

Comment: @Jhosy por qué hacer dos table en el dompdf, recomiendo que hagas un table con dos columnas como deseas y en cada columna le pasas el contenido correspondiente. Yo he usado ese paquete y no me ha dado problema con la distribución del contenido; hago un table y por columnas o filas muestro lo que deseo

Comment: ya lo  intente y es complicado  por que cada tabla tiene información  diferente y se amerita que las 2 tablas queden una  al lado de la otra

Comment: y por que no le metes 2 tablas hijas dentro de una tabla padre???